# Odoo amount_to_text not working correctly with 4 decimal places

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-16

We are trying to implement OpenERP's function "amount_to_text" for total amount in our reports, but have  a problem when the odoo interprets an amount like 20.38 as TWENTY DOLLARS AND THREE THOUSAND EIGHT HUNDRED CENTS, since the prices are with 4 decimal places, like 0.0640.

How can we have the function "amount_to_text" to return the correct text for the amount, or How can we round up only the total sum to 2 decimal places in order for the "amount_to_text" to run correctly?

Thx in advance!

I've tried to setting the rounding precision to 0.01, but it rounds up all prices in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

The method `amount_to_text` of the `res.currency` model reformat your value according to the currency `decimal_places` field value, which it's a computed field that depends on the `rounding` field to calculate the number of decimal places that will be taken into account to return the text representation of the amount.

So you have this 3 options(could be more):

1. Change the stored value of the currency decimal_places field

```py
    currency.write({'decimal_places': 2})
    text = currency.amount_to_text(20.38)
```

But this will affect all of the next conversion operations if the value it's not restored back to what it was

2. Change the amount_to_text definition to check if there is a context value for decimal_places

```py
class Currency(models.Model):
    _inherit = "res.currency"

    def amount_to_text(self, amount):
        self.ensure_one()
        def _num2words(number, lang):
            try:
                return num2words(number, lang=lang).title()
            except NotImplementedError:
                return num2words(number, lang='en').title()

        if num2words is None:
            logging.getLogger(__name__).warning("The library 'num2words' is missing, cannot render textual amounts.")
            return ""

        # Here are the changes
        decimal_places = self.decimal_places
        if self.env.context.get('decimal_places', False):
            decimal_places = self.env.context['decimal_places']
        # End of the changes

        formatted = "%.{0}f".format(decimal_places) % amount
        parts = formatted.partition('.')
        integer_value = int(parts[0])
        fractional_value = int(parts[2] or 0)

        lang = tools.get_lang(self.env)
        amount_words = tools.ustr('{amt_value} {amt_word}').format(
                        amt_value=_num2words(integer_value, lang=lang.iso_code),
                        amt_word=self.currency_unit_label,
                        )
        if not self.is_zero(amount - integer_value):
            amount_words += ' ' + _('and') + tools.ustr(' {amt_value} {amt_word}').format(
                        amt_value=_num2words(fractional_value, lang=lang.iso_code),
                        amt_word=self.currency_subunit_label,
                        )
        return amount_words
```

And use it like: text = currency.with_context(decimal_places=2).amount_to_text(20.38)

3. Build your own function based on the option 2 suggested above